# Runtime error on UVa Online Judge 10038 - Jolly Jumpers

Tags: java, runtime-error

This code runs perfectly on my laptop but I don't know where is the problem that make it do runtime error ?!!

Could anyone please help me find the problem ??


  http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=24&problem=979


Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) /*throws IOException*/
    {
         Main myWork = new Main();
         myWork.begin();
    }


    void begin()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int inputArraySize; // size of array
        int[] inputNumberSequence; // input sequence of numbers saved in array

         while( true )
        {
//            jollyJumpers = new JollyJumpers( inputArraySize );
                        inputArraySize = input.nextInt();
                        inputNumberSequence = new int[ inputArraySize ];

            for( int iii = 0; iii < inputArraySize; ++iii )
            {
                inputNumberSequence[iii] = input.nextInt();
            }

            if( jollyOrNotJolly( inputNumberSequence, inputArraySize ) )
                System.out.println( "Jolly" );

            else
                System.out.println( "Not jolly" );
        }
    }


    boolean jollyOrNotJolly( int[] inputNumberSequence, int inputArraySize )
    {
        int maxInteger = inputNumberSequence[0];
        int minInteger = inputNumberSequence[0];
        int summationOfInputNumberSequence = 0;
        int temporaryElementFromList;
        int summation_From_MinInteger_To_MaxInteger = 0;

        for( int iii = 0; iii < inputArraySize; ++iii )
        {
            temporaryElementFromList = inputNumberSequence[ iii ];

            if( temporaryElementFromList > maxInteger )
                maxInteger = temporaryElementFromList;

            else if( temporaryElementFromList < minInteger )
                minInteger = temporaryElementFromList;

            summationOfInputNumberSequence += temporaryElementFromList;
        }

        for( int jjj = minInteger; jjj <= maxInteger; ++jjj )
        {
            summation_From_MinInteger_To_MaxInteger += jjj;
        }

        return summationOfInputNumberSequence == summation_From_MinInteger_To_MaxInteger;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possibly a little late already but i would suggest wrapping a try-catch block around your code which would catch any exceptions and just print something out. Then you would get a WA error and you can start narrowing down the try-catch until you hit the Runtime Exception again. Then you can correctly determine the place where the exception is thrown.
At least that's the way I did it, when faced with exceptions which I couldn't reproduce at first.

Comment: +1 for information and helping :)
actually I solved it but I didn't remember .. but thanks BTW :)